# Process Builder: Add Volunteer contact to multiple related shifts from single sign up

Tags: process-builder, automation, cross-object

I have the Volunteers for Salesforce app installed in our org.
Business Requirement: When a Volunteer signs up for a shift, ensure that they are also signed up for the recurring shifts as per the related Job Recurrence Schedule.
This means that they sign up once and are part of the 4 shifts as per the program and my WF rules can fire reminder emails for each shift.

How do I achieve this via Process Builder?
The Volunteer contact is created/matched in Salesforce as a Contact and an associated Volunteer Hours record is created in Salesforce which links to the Volunteer shift.
However I am not sure how to automate the creation of multiple Volunteer hours which relates to the other Volunteer Shifts that are all linked together via the Job Recurrence Schedule.

Please see screenshots for more info.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: Apologies I saved before completing the brief. It's completed now.

Answer (score 0):

So you can do 3 record creates with process builder whenever a shift is created... however, you'd get into a loop of sorts.  So you need to have something to differentiate the 'UI created' vs the 'PB created'.  Be it a checkbox or something else... so that you can stop the PB from triggering itself.  Once you get that sorted, you just have to map all the fields to the new records to be created in PB.